# AWS EMR: ssh into task nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I have an EMR cluster set up and running. I need to add a python package to my cluster, and instead of shutting it down and re-boostrapping with the new package, I was wondering if it were possible to ssh into each of the task nodes and pip install the package there. I can ssh into the master node, but I can't find the ip addresses for the associated task nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can SSH into the Core/Task nodes.

You will need to modify the Security Group to allow inbound SSH (port 22) connections.

I tried it myself by **looking in the EC2 console to get the IP address of the Core/Task node**. I then used SSH to connect, just like the master node.

Comment: While adding SSH inbound rule to the core nodes security group, I restricted the source to the security group of the master node. Then I can only ssh into the core nodes from the master. But this avoids to overly expose the core nodes to the public